# How to do an image upload in web.py and save it to the disk

Tags: python, upload, web.py

I need to create a form and have the form upload an image and save it to my disk. Here is my code

```
import web

urls = (
'/hello', 'Index',
'/file_upload_form', 'ThatFile'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/', base = "layout")

class ThatFile(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.file_upload_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(image = "loc")
        open(form.image,'r')
        image_o = form.image.read()
        return render.thatfile(o_image = o_image)

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name = "Nobody", greet = None)
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have tried using PIL Image module but it does not display the image.

Comment: What is the place in your code, where do you think you save a file to disk? I can't find it. And files don't magically save themselves.

Comment: I know I am not sure how to save a file to the disk. I can open a file and print it in a new page now, but I can't save it. So the saving part of the code is not in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something like

```
import shutil
# SKIPPED
def POST(self):
    form = web.input(image={})
    with open('path/to/image.jpg', 'wb') as saved:
        shutil.copyfileobj(form['image'].file, saved)
```